Google Sheets Formula Parse error with IF statement that contains modulus and floors
=IF(E48>0,FLOOR(E48/64)*U48+FLOOR((E48%64)/8)*V48+FLOOR((E48%64)%8)*W48,0)

This is in google sheets and this formula is creating a parse error. I am needing fresh eyes to take a look at the formula.
Context of the formula:
The formula is to help combine prices for items. E48 is the amount of items needed. U48 is the price of the largest bulk option, V48 is the middling bulk price, and W48 is the non-bulk price.
I tried to change the commas as semi colons and tried to do FLOOR.MATH but is giving me the same result.
I've also tried putting curly brackets throughout the formula since it was a recommended answer before I posted the question, but also no dice.

test these in a new cell:  =E48%64

The correct syntax for a mod b is MOD(a,b) not a%b.
=IF(E48>0,
   FLOOR(E48/64)*U48+
   FLOOR(MOD(E48,64)/8)*V48+
   FLOOR(MOD(MOD(E48,64),8)*W48),
  0)

